# I'm looking for an algorithm to calculate the second color using the color mixing formula

Tags: algorithm, colors, calculation, alphablending

Well, I used the search to find the answer to my question, but it didn't get the result I was looking for, so I'll try asking it here:

If I know the formula for mixing colors:

```
resultColorRGB = [round(firstColorR * alpha + secondColorR * (1 - alpha))], [round(firstColorG * alpha + secondColorG * (1 - alpha))], [round(firstColorB * alpha + secondColorB * (1 - alpha))]
```

where *alpha ∈ [0..1]*.

Then how do I find the second color if I know the first color and the color of the result?

For example:
round(35 * alpha + 255 * (1 - alpha)) = 204, round(alpha * 15 + 0 * (1 - alpha)) = 3, round(alpha * 0 + 153 * (1 - alpha)) = 118, alpha = 0.23

I can't use a method for solving a system of linear equations, for two reasons (as I understand it): alpha is not an integer, and the result is calculated by rounding.

But I am sure that there is some way to estimate the approximate calculation, without using iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values were exact, then you have the equation aA+(1-a)B=C, where A and B are your two input colours, a is alpha, and C is the output colour. Each of A, B and C is a triple of red, green, blue, but that makes no difference to the maths; they can each be treated indepdendently.

If you have A and C, and the alpha value a, then you have B=(C-aA)/(1-a). The fact that it's inexact doesn't really matter; you can compute these values exactly, and then round up. You can't get B back exactly since information is lost in the original mixing.